# Deleting multiple buckets from multiple regions

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I am trying to delete a large quantity of buckets spread out over different regions.  I am having difficulty deleting all the objects in the buckets.

This command fails:

```
var objects = client.ListObjectsAsync(new ListObjectsRequest() { BucketName = bucket.BucketName  }).Result;
```

With error:

> The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint

I am guessing this is happening because my client is initialized in a different region.

How can I get objects from a bucket setting region dynamically?

Here is my full code:

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

var buckets = client.ListBucketsAsync().Result;


foreach (var bucket in buckets.Buckets)
{
    if (!keepList.Contains(bucket.BucketName))
    {
        var location = client.GetBucketLocationAsync(new GetBucketLocationRequest() { BucketName = bucket.BucketName }).Result;

        var objects = client.ListObjectsV2Async(new ListObjectsV2Request() { BucketName = bucket.BucketName  }).Result;

        while (true)
        {
            if (objects.IsTruncated)
            {
                objects = client.ListObjectsV2Async(new ListObjectsV2Request() { BucketName = bucket.BucketName, ContinuationToken = objects.NextContinuationToken}).Result; 
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }


        var response = client.DeleteBucketAsync(new DeleteBucketRequest()
        {
            BucketName = bucket.BucketName,
            BucketRegion = location.Location
        }).Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a `GetBucketLocation()` API call that returns the region. Therefore, you could loop through each bucket, retrieve its region, create an S3 client for that region, then call your Delete code.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way around it, I had to statically map string to a new client instance to do the deleting.

```
public static void DeleteFromRegion(string location, string bucketName, AWSCredentials credentials)
{

    AmazonS3Client client = null;
    ListObjectsResponse objects = null;

    switch (location)
    {
        case "us-west-1":
            client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USWest1);
            objects = client.ListObjectsAsync(new ListObjectsRequest() { BucketName = bucketName }).Result;
            DeleteObjects(client, objects, bucketName);
            break;
        case "us-west-2":
            client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
            objects = client.ListObjectsAsync(new ListObjectsRequest() { BucketName = bucketName }).Result;
            DeleteObjects(client, objects, bucketName);
            break;
        case "":
        case "us-east-1":
            client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            objects = client.ListObjectsAsync(new ListObjectsRequest() { BucketName = bucketName }).Result;
            DeleteObjects(client, objects, bucketName);
            break;
        case "us-east-2":
            client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
            objects = client.ListObjectsAsync(new ListObjectsRequest() { BucketName = bucketName }).Result;
            DeleteObjects(client, objects, bucketName);
            break;
        case "eu-west-1":
            client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
            objects = client.ListObjectsAsync(new ListObjectsRequest() { BucketName = bucketName }).Result;
            DeleteObjects(client, objects, bucketName);
            break;
        case "eu-west-2":
            client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);
            objects = client.ListObjectsAsync(new ListObjectsRequest() { BucketName = bucketName }).Result;
            DeleteObjects(client, objects, bucketName);
            break;
        case "eu-west-3":
            client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest3);
            objects = client.ListObjectsAsync(new ListObjectsRequest() { BucketName = bucketName }).Result;
            DeleteObjects(client, objects, bucketName);
            break;
        case "eu-north-1":
            client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.EUNorth1);
            objects = client.ListObjectsAsync(new ListObjectsRequest() { BucketName = bucketName }).Result;
            DeleteObjects(client, objects, bucketName);
            break;
        case "eu-south-1":
            client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.EUSouth1);
            objects = client.ListObjectsAsync(new ListObjectsRequest() { BucketName = bucketName }).Result;
            DeleteObjects(client, objects, bucketName);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Region not recognized");
    }
}

public static void DeleteObjects(AmazonS3Client client, ListObjectsResponse objects, string bucketName)
{

    while (true)
    {
        var kv = new List<KeyVersion>();
        foreach (var o in objects.S3Objects)
        {
            kv.Add(new KeyVersion{ Key = o.Key });
        }

        if (objects.S3Objects.Count == 0) break;

        client.DeleteObjectsAsync(new DeleteObjectsRequest() { BucketName = bucketName, Objects = kv }).Wait();

        if (objects.IsTruncated)
        {
            objects = client.ListObjectsAsync(new ListObjectsRequest() { BucketName = bucketName, Marker = objects.NextMarker }).Result;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You could simplify this by introducing a `Dictionary<string, RegionEndpoint>` which indexes your lookups (the possible values of `location`). That way you're not compromising on duplicated code.